# How do I install R packages on the SageMaker Notebook instance?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I tried to start a R notebook in Sagemaker and I typed

```r
install.packages("disk.frame")
```

and it gave me the error

```
also installing the dependencies ‘listenv’, ‘dplyr’, ‘rlang’, ‘furrr’, 
‘future.apply’, ‘fs’, ‘pryr’, ‘fst’, ‘globals’, ‘future’

Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘pryr’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘fst’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("disk.frame"):
“installation of package ‘disk.frame’ had non-zero exit status”
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

How do I install R packages on Sagemaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to specify a repo. For example, setting the RStudio CRAN repo, I can install perfectly fine.

```r
install.packages("disk.frame", repo="https://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

Comment: I have exactly this problem but I'm afraid that solution didn't work for me...

Comment: Error. Msg to share?

Comment: Warning message in install.packages("RPostgres", repo = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"):
“installation of package ‘RPostgres’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

Comment: Add https to url? Try something other than rpostgres

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker.

This issue has been resolved and you should be able to install R packages using

```
install.packages("disk.frame")
```

or

```
install.packages("disk.frame", repo="https://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

I tested it and was able to successfully install the package with ouput

```
also installing the dependencies ‘listenv’, ‘benchmarkmeData’, ‘doParallel’, ‘bigassertr’, ‘bit’, ‘dplyr’, ‘rlang’, ‘furrr’, ‘future.apply’, ‘fs’, ‘pryr’, ‘fst’, ‘globals’, ‘future’, ‘benchmarkme’, ‘bigreadr’, ‘bit64’

Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting the same error installing odbc on a sagemaker instance. I've tryed 
remotes::install_github()
or 
devtools::install_github()

and also:
install.packages('odbc', repo="https://cran.rstudio.com/")

and pretty much on every instance I get the same warning
“installation of package ‘odbc’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

and if I try to call the package:
Error in library(odbc): there is no package called ‘odbc’
Traceback:

1. library(odbc)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-persistent-custom-r-environment-for-amazon-sagemaker/

And this code worked for me

```
system("conda install -n R -c conda-forge r-rjava")
```

Where r-rjava is the package name from Anaconda cloud. You can find the specific package name/version here: https://anaconda.org/

Answer (score 0):

In SageMaker, click "File" > "New" > "Terminal".

In that terminal type `conda install -c conda-forge r-disk.frame` and push the Enter key.

If you need to install other R packages on SageMaker, search for them on https://anaconda.org/ where it will show you what to enter in the Terminal to download.

Answer (score -1):

if you are still running in to the error, I found a way to get around it. Is very simple. I answered it in this other post, which I had already created. Sorry 'bout that:

[Error installing RODBC or ODBC on a Sagemaker Jupyter NoteBook Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940350/error-installing-rodbc-or-odbc-on-a-sagemaker-jupyter-notebook-instance/59978293#59978293)

Comment: You can mark duplicate questions instead of adding answers here.

Comment: That answer uses a system call to install packages via conda. I get the message `sh: conda: command not found`