# Error installing RODBC or ODBC on a Sagemaker Jupyter NoteBook Instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, r-package

I have been trying to establish a connection to Teradata from a Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook instance. I was trying to do it the way I would through R Studio. But when ever I try to install the package in the instance I get an non-zero exit status error.

I have tried installing the following ways:

```
remotes::install_github()
```

or

```
devtools::install_github()
```

and also:

```
install.packages('odbc', repo="https://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

I tryed the same with RODBC, and I get the same warnings or errors.

Any ideas on how I can get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
If I run this line of code:

```
devtools::install_github("r-dbi/odbc")`
```

I get the following error (This is just an extract):

```
Error: Failed to install 'odbc' from GitHub:
  System command error, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
E> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘odbc’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
E>  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpBuMhbW/Rinst32846cdd20a9/00LOCK-odbc/00new/odbc/libs/odbc.so':
E>   libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E> Error: loading failed
E> Execution halted
E> ERROR: loading failed
E> * removing ‘/tmp/RtmpBuMhbW/Rinst32846cdd20a9/odbc’
E>       -----------------------------------
E> ERROR: package installation failed
Traceback:
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after hours of reading AWS/Sagemaker/Conda/R documentation I arrived at the conclusion that, I don't know how to explain the phenomena.

Nonetheless, I have found a workaround!

So we know how we can install packages through the Jupyter terminal or directly from a cell in the `.ipynb` file. Nonetheless, if you try to run those commands inside the R kernel just like you would on the terminal or in a Python kernel you would run into an error.

Also, for some people installing it in the terminal, or even on a Python kernel might just make `conda` install the package on a different environment.  Yes, turns out there are a couple of environments on your Jupyter instance.

So, to get to the point, just like I said, you would use a `conda install` command, not a `pip`, `sudo` or `yum` command.

Make your life easier. Here is the code that you would need to run on your R Kernel cell, to install a package directly to the correct environment if, `install.packages()` and `install_github()` didn't work:

```
system(command = 'conda install -c r packageName --yes')
```

Example:

```
system(command = 'conda install -c r tidyverse --yes')
```

And that's it. After that you can call `library()` and resume your R workflow as you do.

Hope this helps guys!

Comment: not every CRAN package is on conda. e.g. disk.frame is not

Comment: I am running a Jupyter SageMaker notebook connected to an EMR cluster for Spark via a SparkMagic kernel. I got this message when I ran the command above:
 `sh: conda: command not found`